# If the imit as $x\to c$ of $|f(x)|$ exists, does the limit as $x\to c$ of $f(x)$ exist?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, solution-verification

I'm asked to prove or give a counterexample of the following:

If $\lim_{x\to c} |f(x)|$ exists then $\lim_{x\to c} f(x)$ exists.

My initial thought is that the statement is false, and a piecewise function, f(x):

\begin{cases}-1 & x\leq0\\ 1 & x\gt 0 \\ \end{cases}

would suffice as a counterexample. Am I right in thinking this? I'm not too confident so I was looking for either affirmation or a pointer in the right direction if I've got it wrong here. Thanks!

Comment: To be a counterexample, among other things, you need $\lim_{x\to c} |f(x)|$ to exist. But $\lim_{x\to c} |f(x)|$ doesn't exist for your function. An analogy: Trying to find a counterexample to the claim that every penny is made of copper, and you show us a nickel. *(moments later)* OK, the change you've made gives a counterexample.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro Thank you, that helps. Turns out I made a typo in the original post but after the edit I'm glad to hear I was right in my thinking.

Comment: Incidentally, probably the following is what you're supposed to notice. There's a theorem that says if you apply a continuous function to a continuous function (i.e. function composition), then the result will be a continuous function. Moreover, this is also true more generally if we just consider limits (and not the value at a given point) -- if $f(x)$ has a limit at $x=a,$ and $g(x)$ is continuous (or even if we only know $g(x)$ has a limit at $x = f(a)\,),$ then $f(g(x)$ has a limit at $x=a.$ A special case is when $g(x) = |x|.$ This problem shows the converse fails, even for $g(x)=|x|.$

Answer (score 2):

You can do something based on [Diriclet function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_function). Say $$f(x)=\begin{cases}1, x\in \mathbb Q\\-1,x\in\mathbb R\setminus\mathbb Q\end{cases}$$
Then $|f(x)|=1$ for any $x\in \mathbb R$, so $\lim_{x\to c} |f(x)|=1$. But the limit of $f(x)$ does not exist for any $c$.